# TinyMCE Editor - How to make the Textarea word-wrap without scrollbars just like MS Word?

Tags: tinymce

When I enter a line like `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.....aaaaaa` with no spaces in between, TinyMCE editor will create a scroll-bar automatically. How do I make it go to the next line instead? With spaces between words, TinyMCE wraps fine. This is how MS Word works for example. I think this feature is called Text-Wrap?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp Solves the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will have to do something on your own.
You could check for the paragraph width and if it overflows a predefined value you could insert a space before the next a.

Comment: Thanks though there is a simple solution thanks to CSS 3 :-) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp